# Failed sliding glass door flashing tape

Tags: waterproofing, exterior, flashing

Installed a new sliding glass door recently, and the flashing tape I used: [Nashua Tape](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Nashua-Tape-6-in-x-50-ft-Select-Window-and-Door-Flashing-Tape-1343003/206495170) adhered at first but completely failed within a day or so and is now flapping in the breeze.

How should I go about fixing this?  Should I leave the tape there and attempt to adhere it with something else?  Should I cut the tape back and put another, more rugged tape product over the top?

Comment: Could you describe and/or add some pics showing how you used this tape? Did you follow the [instructions](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/17/1798f41f-1726-4d9c-9d55-f164d4aec905.pdf)? It sounds like you've left it exposed to the weather (see steps 7 & 8 in the instructions).

Comment: Thanks, yes that's exactly what I did.  I didn't have replacement shingles handy, and the tape was left exposed.  My fault for thinking that this tape was built for weather exposure.